# Sometimes get blank screen after grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm having a problem with a new computer from here: http://www.dabs.com/products/zoostorm-value-pentium-dual-core-g840-6gb-ram-250gb-hdd-no-os-7XQL.html?refs=459610000&src=2

At first I installed Linux Mint and everything seemed to work fine until I turned the computer on the next day and it got stuck on a blank screen after GRUB.  Booting using recovery mode it gets stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk" indefinitely.  After trying to fix this I decided to try kubuntu, the problem occurs just the same.  I have found a way to boot kubuntu by using the System Settings option at GRUB, and then selecting 'save and exit' in the BIOS settings, after which the computer will boot normally.  Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter from a CD or stick, install this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair , then run it.

It should work after I think.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering, just tried it and unfortunately it had no effect.